# Difference between atoll and (long int)?

Tags: c++

Excuse me if this is a bad question. Most probably it is. But I am under the impression that `(long int)[some string]` should convert string into a long int. That doesn't seem to be the case as I just wrote a sample program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int firstNum = atoll(argv[1]);
        int secondNum = atoll(argv[2]);

        int sum = firstNum + secondNum;

        long int firstArg = (long int)argv[1];
        long int secondArg = (long int)argv[2];

        long int argSum = firstArg + secondArg;

        cout << "The argSum is: " << argSum << ", which is same as sum: " << sum << endl;

}
```

I came under this impression because of a code I was reading given as under. An explanation would help me build some knowledge. Thanks.

```
srv.request.a = atoll(argv[1]);
srv.request.b = atoll(argv[2]);
  if (client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Sum: %ld", (long int)srv.response.sum);
  }
```

Comment: (long int)argv[1] - this just casting pointer to long int - so it has nothing to do with output of atoll

Comment: *But I am under the impression that (long int)[some string] should convert string into a long int* Where did you get this impression?  It is not correct.

Comment: `argv[1]` is a `char *` i.e. an address in memory.

Comment: Why would anyone need atoll then?

Comment: @n.m.: To parse the string representation of a value to the `long long` representation of that same value.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sigh. Why would anyone need that if a simple cast did exactly the same thing?

Comment: @n.m.: As the various answers below, and comments above, detail, because it does *not*.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sigh. Let's break it down. *If* a simple cast *did* convert a string. That's subjunctive mood. The if clause contains a hypothesis that may or may not hold. We're trying to determine its veracity by exploring its consequences in the following clause. Assuming it does hold, we can ask ourselves why *would* anyone need a function that does the same thing then? It's a rhetorical question. The intended answer is that such function *would* not be needed. Since it actually exists, the original hypothesis doesn't look too good.

Comment: @n.m. Sure, because no language has ever had more than one way to do a thing.  (I'll leave it to you to translate that into your fancy logic talk.)

Comment: @ScottHunter it's one thing to have two different tools, each with its own range of abilities that happen to overlap, and another thing to have two nearly identical tools. In particular, one doesn't see too many library functions in the standard liibrary that exactly replicate each other or some built-in language construct. Note I'm not saying it's a logical impossibility, merely an.indicator that something could be wrong.

Comment: @Viper: A cast of the form `(Type)Value` is shorthand, but it varies what it's shorthand _for_. It could be a `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`  (or a combination). This depends on the intended Type and the type of the source Value. In your case, the Type is `long long` and the Value is a `char*`. That means your cast is shorthand for a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am under the impression that (long int)[some string] should convert string into a long int.

You've misunderstood. *Explicit conversion* (aka *cast*) does nothing of the sort. When converting a "pointer to `char`" (which is the type of your string) into an integer will result in the integer value of the address that the pointer points to - possibly losing precision if the target integer type cannot represent the memory address value.

> Difference between atoll and (long int)?

`atoll` converts a character string to an integer value based on what digits the contents of the string represents.

An explicit conversion has different behaviour depending on the type of the argument, but in case of character pointer, see the paragraph above.

Comment: Thank you! In my example the casting was being done on a pointer so I got nonsense. From what I understand from your very nicely explained comment, if the casting was done on a string that had a proper numeric value (but still a string). The result would be a conversion to   long int

Answer (score 2):

`atoll` is a function which parses a string to yield the numeric value it represents as a `long long` (which you then stuff into an `int`).

*Casting*, which is what `(long int)arg[0]` is doing, tells the compiler to interpret one value as another type.  In your case, the thing you are trying to interpret is the pointer to a character, not the value that is represented by the string it points to the start of.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am under the impression that (long int)[some string] should convert string into a long int.

That is not correct.

What it does is take the pointer value that represents the string and convert it into a `long int`. There is no telling what that value would be from one run of the program to the next.

The use of `atoll(argv[1])`, on the other hand, does the proper extraction of the number from the string.

Answer (score 0):

(long int)[some string] is a cast, it does no actual processing of the data, it just tells the compiler to interpret whatever data [some string] is as if it was a long int, in this case you'll be seeing the offset of the string in memory, as a C string is just a pointer to some data.

atoll is a function which parses the string and converts the text to an integer value.

Comment: Thanks Luke! One follow up question. When you say, in case of casting, that the compiler interprets whatever data [string] is, as a long int. And atoll actually converts the text to an int ... can you say a line about what is the difference between interpreting as an int and converting to an int.